# Which was the last war in which swords were used?

Tags: military, war

Which was the last war in which swords were actively used as the primary weapon by an army?

Comment: Define 'Used'. Do you mean as primary offensive weapon on a battlefield?

Comment: Are you including cavalry? Use by officers?

Comment: [Related](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/308/when-were-swords-last-used-in-european-warfare)

Comment: Do we count machetes as swords?  If so then just look back to the Rwandan civil war,  tons of them were used!

Comment: You'll need to define "actively used", "sword" and "army", and possibly "war".

Comment: The 1993 Rwandan genocide involved machete attacks. Was that war?

Comment: They could actively use them for parades or for cans opening... Better change that to "use as a primary or at least a secondary weapon"

Comment: @ed.hank Excellent! Surely, we should count them as swords. And in thick forest they remain effective even now! That should be the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Swords were certainly used in World War II.

Japanese officers carried [Guntō swords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunt%C5%8D) and used them as hand-to-hand weapons.

One eccentric British officer, ["Mad Jack" Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Churchill) used a broadsword, along with a longbow, through the war.

Answer (score 4):

During the WWII Russian, Polish, German, French and Italian cavalry regiments existed. And they really used swords. The use against tanks is obviously a fallacy, but in the sudden attacks against infantry the swords worked!

[Here is a large collection of contemporary photos and pictures.](http://antonrumata.livejournal.com/2157.html)

So, these armies had not only CARRIED swords, not only USED swords, but  even COUNTED on them in battle!

Comment: Thank you. Corrected. In comments here: http://wiki.istmat.info/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84:%D1%81_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8 you can find an example of cavalry attack against tanks and motorbikes, but it was not a sword attack, of course.